# url not valid on wp_safe_remote_get

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I develop an application using the woocommerce v3 API.

I want push an image by remote_url.

my url : http://tshirt-previewer.internal.teezily.com/media/W1siZiIsIjIwMTUvMTAvMjgvMTQvNTAvMzMvNGQ0NmVhYzAtYmVlNC00Y2IzLTlkN2QtZDM5ZmJlNzFmMWM5L0dJNjQwMDBfZnJvbnQucG5nIl0sWyJwIiwicHJldmlld3MiLDIwLCJyb3lhbCBibHVlIix7InBvc2l0aW9uX3giOjM2LCJwb3NpdGlvbl95IjoxLCJ3aWR0aCI6NjIsImhlaWdodCI6NjIsImRlc2lnbl91cmwiOiJodHRwczovL3RlZXppbHktcGx1cy5zMy5hbWF6b25hd3MuY29tL3VwbG9hZHMvZGVzaWduL3BpY3R1cmUvMzM3Ny9pbWFnZS0xMjAweDE2MDAuanBnIn1dXQ/GI64000_front.png?sha=989266d5133de145

But I can't upload it to Woocommerce by the Product API update

I found in the code the issue the image is downloaded by wp_safe_remote_get from Wordpress. But this methode think my URL is not safe.

Why is not safe ?
Can i add some whitlist system to avoid considere this URL like unsafe ?

Comment: if you have the correct function name, you can overwrite the function using patchwork or something, its far from ideal but you can add your whitelist implementation into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Wordpress code seems to do a same-host check on urls that are fetched using `wp_safe_remote_get()`.

Here's the source: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/c73a812109e1a64ecf21b6a198f949c58d1f2674/wp-includes/http.php

The significant part is the `wp_http_validate_url` function, and in particular lines 524-530, which are here:

```
$parsed_home = @parse_url( get_option( 'home' ) );
if ( isset( $parsed_home['host'] ) ) { 
    $same_host = ( strtolower( $parsed_home['host'] ) === strtolower( $parsed_url['host'] ) || 'localhost' === strtolower( $parsed_url['host'] ) );
} else {
    $same_host = false;
}
```

If `$same_host` is `false`, the method treats the url as not safe.

There's no whitelist that I can see. You'd probably need to edit the code to use `wp_remote_get()` if you want to avoid the problem.

UPDATE: the preceding argument is wrong. The code returns the url even if the host is not the same as long as the port is normal.

Comment: Thanks to pointing me the issue. But it's not exactly that. When the same_host == false there are a check between the IP and the host : https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/c73a812109e1a64ecf21b6a198f949c58d1f2674/wp-includes/http.php#L537 and check if the IP is local or not : https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/c73a812109e1a64ecf21b6a198f949c58d1f2674/wp-includes/http.php#L543 In my case the IP is local because the WP and the host are on the same VPC on AWS. so DNS return local IP

Comment: Sorry - I was just wrong. I've run the url through `wp_http_validate_url` and it returns fine. So it's not the url validation that's failing. What error do you get?

Answer (score 1):

If the host of the URL contains one of the following symbols, the URL will be rejected: `:#?[]`

Try removing `?sha=989266d5133de145` if without this image can be retrieved
.

Answer (score 0):

I've been try to upload your image on live server, I use woocommerce v3 API approach, and all is working fine. Maybe you need to re-check your apps function, your server, firewall, increase your timeout http, etc, And the issue may come from image server.

https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/api/class-wc-api-products.php#L2333

```
protected function upload_image_from_url( $image_url, $upload_for = 'product_image' ) {
        $file_name  = basename( current( explode( '?', $image_url ) ) );
        $wp_filetype    = wp_check_filetype( $file_name, null );
        $parsed_url     = @parse_url( $image_url );
        // Check parsed URL.
        if ( ! $parsed_url || ! is_array( $parsed_url ) ) {
            throw new WC_API_Exception( 'woocommerce_api_invalid_' . $upload_for, sprintf( __( 'Invalid URL %s', 'woocommerce' ), $image_url ), 400 );
        }
        // Ensure url is valid.
        $image_url = str_replace( ' ', '%20', $image_url );
        // Get the file.
        $response = wp_safe_remote_get( $image_url, array(
            'timeout' => 10
        ) );
        if ( is_wp_error( $response ) || 200 !== wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $response ) ) {
            throw new WC_API_Exception( 'woocommerce_api_invalid_remote_' . $upload_for, sprintf( __( 'Error getting remote image %s', 'woocommerce' ), $image_url ), 400 );
        }
...
```

As your issue `wp_safe_remote_get` that you get from, we can tweaking those function in out just to test `wp_safe_remote_get` to upload image by url.

and here the response header of your image by `wp_safe_remote_get`

```
Array
(
    [headers] => Array
        (
            [content-disposition] => filename="GI64000_front.png"
            [content-length] => 934080
            [content-type] => image/png
            [etag] => "6f19381f5b2ae0657f6e7945d7ca4bac05e3ad3a"
            [server] => nginx
            [expires] => Mon, 20 Mar 2017 19:20:54 GMT
            [last-modified] => Sun, 20 Mar 2016 19:20:54 GMT
            [connection] => close
            [date] => Wed, 23 Mar 2016 00:19:28 GMT
            [content-encoding] => gzip
        )

    [body] => �PNG
... I skip this part ...

[response] => Array
        (
            [code] => 200
            [message] => OK
        )

    [cookies] => Array
        (
        )

    [filename] => 
)
```